# How to get a list of instances which are referencing another instance in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

JVM can mark an object to be garbage collected when its unsused (there isn't any reference to it).

Is there any way in Java to get a list of objects which have a reference to a given object?

Comment: Is the JVM running in debug mode? Can you use [JPDA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html) or [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/)?

Comment: It's a theorical question, not related with a concrete environment. Any aproach is allowed for answers. Just need an example to get a collection inside a Java program.

Comment: Most Java GC algorithms utilize "mark and sweep" to identify unused objects.  This means that they never collect lists of objects referencing a given object.